# Is a leap of a 4th in the Alto voice too large when voice leading?

Tags: voice-leading

I am trying to voice lead IV6 V6 I in A major with an ascending bassline and this is the best I could come up with but there is a leap of a 4th. Is this too much? Could someone please tell me what Im doing wrong?
[image]

Comment: You have parallel octaves between soprano and tenor.  Fix those, and you may find that you no longer have a need for the leap of a fourth in the alto.

Comment: thanks but I would still like to know if a 4th is allowed?

Comment: Any other way I tried it then I have parallel 5ths :( and I cant double the G # in the V6 chord either since it is the leading tone

Answer (score 2):

The leap of a fourth is fine in any voice.  In the sort of pseudo-19th-century-hymnody style of four-part writing that many music theory textbooks use, leaps bigger than a fourth or fifth are relatively rare in upper voices (but can sometimes occur).

(I call it 19th-century hymnody style, because it's not really "chorale style," despite what textbooks say.  Actual Bach chorales frequently have giant leaps all over the place.)

To fix your voice-leading problem here, the quickest solution is to have the tenor move up to E, i.e., D-E-C♯.  That's also a better doubling for the V chord anyway.

Comment: Also commonly taught that a leap should be followed by a return by step in the opposite direction.

Answer (score 2):

When roots move by single step it's a special voice leading situation, because there are no common tones to hold between triads, so I first looked at the root position standard movement. The basic voice leading is to have all the upper voices move opposite the bass to the closest next tones.

[image]

...note colors are orange=tenor, green=alto, blue=bass.

But what happens when `F#` to `G#` is taken from that voice leading and placed in the bass?

[image]

Notice the desired ascending bass of `F# G# A` then *splits* the `F# G#` part of the line between the tenor and alto voices. If we remove the root position `D E` bass and then drop tenor `F#` and alto `G#` down into the bass we account for the leap of `A` down to `E`. It's the remnants of the initial parts `A` in alto and `E` in tenor.

If we consider the descending `A` to `E` as an alto leap and then fill a tenor for four parts with doubled roots we get...

[image]

...the second harmonization just holds the tenor `D` to get a dominant seventh `V`.

But that's not necessarily the best way to harmonize bass `F# G# A`. It's just a way to show how we end up with leaping voices.

The desired ascending bass `F# G# A` isn't root position harmony, so we don't have to move all the upper voices opposite the bass. Fenaroli's rule of the octave give these positions for ascending bass `^6 ^7 ^1`...

[image]

...that shows the bass/soprano movement from `IV6` to `V6/5` in parallel thirds/sixths or oblique holding the subdominant to get a seventh for `V6/5`.

Comment: Thanks Michael. So in your opinion which do you think is the best way to Harmonize the ^6 ^7 ^8 bassline? Changing the V to a 65 chord certainly seems to smooth it out a bit.

Comment: I don't think of this in terms of "best" harmonization. Other than the first example, root position, upper voices in closed position, as just a _model_ of voice leading principles, you have _choices_. Fenaroli gave three examples just to cover the various endings of the soprano. But, you can reduce those to simply say `IV6 V6 I` gets harmonized as ascending `6/3` chords as a "prototype" then the seventh is added for `V65`. You can rearrange the voices into different octave for open positions, or make typical omissions for 3 or 2 part harmony.

Comment: I would note that the Fenaroli examples aren't really about "voices" in the literal vocal sense, or in the "hymn-texture" abstract music theory sense.  Fenaroli was writing a keyboard harmonization for a given bass line.  As Michael says in the comment, you can spread out the notes as needed, but as we can see in the examples, "voices" tend to appear or disappear on a whim in many keyboard realizations (often to avoid parallels or other voice-leading problems).

Comment: Yes, not true voices/parts. My original source for Fenaroli is the author Gjerdingen and he did explain the rule wasn't a voice leading model. In fact, from the Fenaroli original (facsimiles) I've seen, the rules were only a _figured bass_ line, no actual upper voices written out.

Answer (score 1):

A leap of a 4th is fine.  But try to make each part a coherent melodic line.  It can be difficult to make the alto an INTERESTING melodic line in hymn-style harmony, but at least try to avoid random jumps.

If you want a 'rule', try not to follow a big leap with another one in the same direction.